# Translate Keys to char

Tags: .net, winforms, keycode

I want to translate a given set of `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` and a `System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage` to the corresponding `System.Char`.

Tried some experiments with [`MapVirtualKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646307.aspx), but there is now way to consider keyboard state, and [`ToUnicodeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646322.aspx) is a pain with *dead keys*.

*My goal is a function ...*

```
static char? FromKeys(Keys keys, InputLanguage inputLanguage)
{
    // As I think what can be helpful and I got trying to find a solution for this problem:
    Keys vkCode = keys & Keys.KeyCode;
    Keys modifiers = keys & Keys.Modifiers;

    byte[] keyboardState = new byte[256];

    keyboardState[vkCode] = 1 << 7;

    if (modifiers.HasFlag(Keys.Shift))
    {
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = 1 << 7;
    }

    if (modifiers.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
    {
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.ControlKey] = 1 << 7;
    }

    if (modifiers.HasFlag(Keys.Alt))
    {
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.Menu] = 1 << 7;
    }

    // [Put your code here]
}
```

*... which should be called like this:*

```
FromKeys(Keys.A | Keys.Shift, InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage); // = 'A'
FromKeys(Keys.Escape, InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage); // = null
FromKeys(Keys.Oemtilde, InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("de-DE"))); // = 'ö'
FromKeys(Keys.E | Keys.Control | Keys.Alt, InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("de-DE"))); // = '€'
```

(Be aware of `Keys.Shift` and `Keys.ShiftKey`!)

**How would this function look like?**

*The answer I'll choose should provide a way to translate one "normal" `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` with an optional combination of the modifiers (`Keys.Shift`, `Keys.Alt`, `Keys.Control`) to a `System.Char`. Multiple successively calls have to result in the same character. No hardcoded keyboard layouts, the `InputLanguage` defines the layout to use.*

*As a help to understand what I'm trying to to: Generate a `KeyPressEventArgs` with just the `KeyEventArgs` (and the correct `InputLangauge`) given.*

***Dead keys*** should not affect `FromKeys`!

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment?

Comment: @ChrisF What would that course be? =D  
No, its just a project i'm working on in which i have events equal to the `KeyDown` in _WinForms_, but not the `KeyPress` ...

Comment: It's just the phrase "Be aware of Keys.Shift and Keys.ShiftKey" struck me as something that would be written on an assignment ;)

Comment: Ah ok :D, I'm actually sitting a long time on this and this was a trap i fell in. `Keys.Shift` is the .NET way of saying the other `Keys` are modified with this. And `Keys.ShiftKey` is the real key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that seems to do what you're looking for - if I understood it correctly :-)

```
    public static char? FromKeys(Keys keys, InputLanguage inputLanguage)
    {
        return FromKeys(keys, inputLanguage, true);
    }

    private static char? FromKeys(Keys keys, InputLanguage inputLanguage, bool firstChance)
    {
        if (inputLanguage == null)
        {
            inputLanguage = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
        }

        byte[] keyStates = new byte[256];

        const byte keyPressed = 0x80;
        keyStates[(int)(keys & Keys.KeyCode)] = keyPressed;
        keyStates[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = ((keys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift) ? keyPressed : (byte)0;
        keyStates[(int)Keys.ControlKey] = ((keys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control) ? keyPressed : (byte)0;
        keyStates[(int)Keys.Menu] = ((keys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt) ? keyPressed : (byte)0;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10);
        int ret = ToUnicodeEx(keys, 0, keyStates, sb, sb.Capacity, 0, inputLanguage.Handle);
        if (ret == 1)
            return sb[0];

        if (ret == -1)
        {
            // dead letter
            if (firstChance)
            {
                FromKeys(keys, inputLanguage, false);
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int ToUnicodeEx(Keys wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags, IntPtr dwhkl);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working well _(in simple cases)_, but I can not depend on `GetKeyboardState`, but it may be possible to generate that state array with the modifiers _(see updated question, i'm trying to find some code for that)_. Whats not working so far: _dead keys_ are messing up the keyboard buffer and can change the result of a call to FromKeys. So: `FromKeys(Keys.A, ...)` should always result in `'a'`.

Comment: @ordag - Yes, you can emulate the GetKeyboardState, but I'm not sure to really understand what you mean. In my tests, FromKeys(Keys.A, ...) always return an 'a' - my tests are coming from a real KeyEventArg.

Comment: I don't know what `Keys.Oem5` is on your keyboard, but after `FromKeys(Keys.Oem5, InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage)`, a `FromKeys(Keys.A, InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage)` call results in `'â'`. This is caused by the keyboard buffer which changes the result but must not be flushed because that would affect other applications. _(So a call to `FromKeys` should be independent of any current keyboard state)_

Comment: your solution is working really good. But if there is already a _dead key_ in the buffer _(maybe from a normal keystroke)_ it interferes with `FromKeys` .. and just removing it is not an option because that would affect programs/the user out of the scope of the method.

Comment: Still haven't found a better solution, thx _(dead keys can mess up everything though)_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this will work, but you might take a look at [ToUnicodeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It lets you set the keyboard state as well as the input locale.

Another possibility, although pretty involved, would be to turn your events into strings that are compatible with [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx), and then send the string to your application.

You'd have to set the culture for the main thread and use a separate thread to do the sending.

I don't know how well something like that would work, and it's kind of expensive (in terms of time) to try it.

Comment: I tried with ToUnicodeEx and its working partially well ... still have some problems with keys like grave accent and the keyboard layout buffer.