# ToUnicodeEx - Skip Keyboard Buffer

Tags: winapi, keyboard

*Analogous to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214326/translate-keys-to-char) on how to translate a `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` set to a `System.Char`*

I'm trying to convert a *Virtual-Key Code* to a character with [`ToUnicodeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646322.aspx)
Some keys become *dead-key characters* which are stored in a buffer for the next call *(`ToUnicodeEx` returing `-1`)*, an other times one of them is already stored there.

**But I want to skip that buffer and my program should not affect/be affected from it.

Is there a way for what I need?**

*(So: If my virtual-key code translates to a dead-key, it should not remain in the buffer, and if there is a dead-key in the buffer, it should not change my current function call)*

Comment: Dead keys are an unsolved problem.

Comment: If it stored a dead-key character and returned -1, could you follow up immediately with another call to ToUnicodeEx with dummy data that will flush the buffer?

Comment: @Jon Yeah could do that to not affect future calls, but what can i do if there is already something stored in the buffer? (from previous keyboard input)

Comment: @ordag Just had the same problem, ended up doing the dummy call before the actual call.

Comment: @Zarat That would affect the current user, as his legit input (maybe completely unrelated to the program) would be flushed out the buffer.

Comment: @ordag I'm aware of that but there is no better solution. I'm building my tables during initialization of a new dialog (which Windows will give keyboard focus to) so the user isn't expected to be typing.